# Reducing memory overhead of a simple sorted array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an array of items that are sorted by a key value, items are retrieved by doing a binary search. Simplified version of the items would look something like this:

```
struct Item
{
    uint64_t key;
    uint64_t data;
};
```

I'm looking for ways to reduce the overhead of the key. The key value is not used for anything except searching. Assuming insert cost is not a concern, but retrieval cost is, what alternative data structure could I use to reduce the bookkeeping overhead to something less than 64-bits per item?

The only other "gotcha" is that I need to be able to detect the case where a key isn't present in the set.

Comment: What can you tell us about the keys (e.g. are they consecutive)?

Comment: What are the specific reasons for keeping the key 64bit? How many items do you expect to store? Is this running on embedded hardware? In that case some lower-level optimizations may be possible (32 bit processor, special ASM commands?). Also, is this a specific language question? I know ruby has things like symbols that can be used as keys and that don't have the memory overhead of full Strings and such.

Comment: @Cubic: Looks like C to me...

Comment: @aix: the keys are basically random, a 64-bit checksum of an external piece of data

Comment: @Cubic: the number of items stored is pretty low compared to the key size, about 200,000 - 300,000. The key is 64-bits for several reasons, outside of the scope of this question. The question is not really language specific, but lets say C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious possibility would be to treat your key as 8 individual bytes and build a trie out of them. This combines the common prefixes in your keys, so if you have (for example) a thousand Items with the same first byte, you only store that first byte once instead of a thousand times.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to detect the absence of a key from your set, you need to store your keys in one way or another. Since the keys are random, you can't compress them into fewer than 64 bits by using clever data structures. Ergo, they way you're doing it now is optimal in terms of memory consumption.

If there was some structure, or predictability, to the keys it would be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

If the "keys are basically random", then you don't have much option other than what you are using right now. For 64bit integers you cannot even assume a dense set of keys.

Are there anything else  about the keys that you can exploit? ... Maybe a lot of keys are near to each other ... or something else? ... In this cases you can build multi-level hash tables or tries for storing your data.